# JS Array a['1'] doesnot gives an error

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have declared an array `a = [1,2,3,4,5]`

When I write `a[1]` it *returns 2* which is perfectly fine but when I write `a['1']` it also *gives me 2* instead of giving an error.

I was expecting an error there. Why does it behave like that??

Answer (score 2):

All property names are strings.

If you pass a number, it gets converted to a string before being used to look up the property value.

```js
console.log(1 == '1');
```

Comment: But isn't indexes of an array, numeric?

Comment: @Rajesh — No. They are strings like any other property. Properties, in arrays, with names that are `==` to integers are special cased (e.g. by the `length` getter property), but they are still strings.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware about that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, array is also object having property names as `0,1,2,....n`

> Property names must be strings. This means that non-string objects cannot be used as keys in the object. Any non-string object, including a number, is typecasted into a string via the `toString` method. [[**Ref**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Property_names)]

Answer (score 0):

In JS an `Array` is basically an `Object` and thus mostly behaves like one. In this case, these are equivalent as long as you dont access `Array`'s `.length` or try iterating `a`:

```
const a = {"0": foo};    
const b = ["foo"];
```

Also this would work:

```
const a = ["foo"];
a.bar = "baz";

console.log(a);
```

So that `a[1]` and `a['1']` are equivalent is exactly what's to be expected.